# Communication from Jetson TX2 to PC

Tags: usb, ipc, ethernet, serial-communication, nvidia-jetson

I have a Jetson TX2 running a machine vision algorithm, and I'd like to communicate the output from this board to a Windows 10 PC in some way.

The data being sent is tiny - on the scale of a vector of ~100 floats at worst, and the refresh rate I need is nothing crazy - the limiting factor will be that the frames from the camera going to the Jetson board are being grabbed at ~60 FPS.

I'm open to suggestions using either Ethernet cables (preferred) or USB cables. The code on the Jetson is written in Python, and the output will be picked up by a C# application running on the Windows PC. Neither of the computers will be connected to the internet in general.

Since I'm not scaling up my system (it'll only ever be 1 Jetson TX2 -> 1 PC) I'd appreciate the easiest possible solution, rather than most technically robust!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about using rabitmq (message broker) to control sending and receiving messages (your data). It will look like this picture. You sender (Jetson) will store message in message queue. And your receiver (window PC) will keep connecting to the queue through local IP. When new message come, receiver will read it and do further processing.

[image: Send and receive]

There is example about using dotnet at https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html . So it's very easy to implement. Wouldn't take more than 2 hours.

Hope that help

Answer (score 0):

The Jetson itself doesn't do communication.
It's up to its **carrier board**.
Most of them provide an Ethernet port.
Hence, it's quite easy to implement almost any transport over IP.
I'd choose something like mere TCP socket to do it.